# How do I change default controller addresses in Auth::routes();?

Tags: laravel-5.8

How do I change The set of default controller addresses in (Auth::routes();)?

For example,
Change

App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm

into

App\Http\Controllers\Adminauth\LoginController@showLoginForm

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the routes by implementing them yourself [as posted here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-the-loginregister-url-in-laravel-55?page=0). Does that answer your question?